# Azure New-AzureRMResourceGroupDeployment Failed with "The blob name in URL contains a slash. This is presently not supported for disks"

Tags: azure, powershell-2.0, azure-storage

I am trying to use the New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment command to create a bunch of stuff in ARM.  It does not seem to like the blob name.  Unfortunately, I cannot change them.  "osDisk.vhd.uri",
    "message": "The blob name in URL https://dynd748adc71297ac46v2.blob.core.windows.net/dynamicsdeployments/AX2012R3-Dev-Train
ing-DEV/DEV/efa12314-928a-4fc7-b86b-12327fed2275/OsDisk.vhd contains a slash. This is presently not supported for disks."  Does anyone know how to get past this or if there is an update somewhere that will "support" the slashes?  I am pretty sure Blob storages will always have a slash somewhere in the name

Comment: Do you have a `/` in the name of the blob or the blobcontainer? That is not allowed as per the conventions listed here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/Naming-and-Referencing-Containers--Blobs--and-Metadata?redirectedfrom=MSDN Also **one cannot create a blob or blob container using ARM, did you mean a storage account?** am a little confused?

Comment: Very bad formatting. Don't know what's quotation and what's text

Answer (score 0):

Azure does not support virtual folders ("/") in the VHD uris. Can you rename the blobs and remove all the /.

Comment: since when does it not?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you are using Resource Manager Template to deploy your VM based on the Page Blob(.vhd file). As mentioned in this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/Naming-and-Referencing-Containers--Blobs--and-Metadata?redirectedfrom=MSDN), the Blob could contain slash '/'. For a simple test, I tried to attach my .vhd file to my VM on Azure Portal, then I got the same error as you provided.

https://brucechen01.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/2016-11-18/test.vhd

[image]

Upon the test, we could find that the page blob (.vhd) with the URL containing a slash is not supported as a disk attached to Azure VM. For a workaround, you could leverage [Azure Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/) to rename your page blob or follow this official [tutorial](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ileong/2016/02/18/renaming-a-vhd-or-blob-file/) to rename a vhd by using PowerShell command.